# Laravel 5.1 doesn't process queued job

Tags: laravel, queue

I am testing the Laravel 5.1 job queue system, which is kept in a db table. I run this command:

```
php artisan queue:listen
```

Then I dispatch the queueable job and I can then verify it is in my queue table, but the queued job is never acted upon. Is there something more that I should be doing to get this to work? I have also tried

```
php artisan queue:work
```

but that does nothing as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added a queue specifier like so and now it works:

```
php artisan queue:listen --queue="email"
```